# How to authenticate and redirect a user to his 'own' page in Jersey REST service

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jersey

How to authenticate and redirect a user to his own page i.e to www.mysite.com/"user's email".

I am using the following algo which is not working...

userDB in User class:

```
Map<String,String> userdata=new HashMap<String,String>();
```

First my login process form :

```
@Path("/login")
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public void login(
            @FormParam("email") String emailc,
            @FormParam("password") String pass,
            @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse
    ) throws IOException,RuntimeException {
        User u1=new User();
        pass=u1.getPassword();
        emailc=u1.getEmailaddrs();

              boolean checked=false;
        boolean exists;
        exists=u1.userdata.containsKey(emailc);
        if(exists){
            String mypass =u1.userdata.get(emailc);
            if(mypass==pass){
                checked=true;
            }else{
                checked=false;
            }
        }else{
            checked=false;
        }
        if(!checked){
            //User Doesn't exists
            servletResponse.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/MySite/pages/Create_Profile.html");
        }else{
            servletResponse.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/MySite/{email}");  <<<< How to redirect using @FormParam("email")   
        }
    }
```

createprofile

```
@POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public void newUser(
            @FormParam("email") String email,
            @FormParam("password") String password,
            @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse
    ) throws IOException {
            User u = new User(email,password);
            User.userdata.put(email,password);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"?

Comment: its always going to Create_Profile !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `userdata [Map]` looks wrong to me. Is it a part of user class, is it non static or static ? 
If it is non static then every time you will do `new User()` .. that map will be initialized and it will have no data in it. Hence `u1.userdata.containsKey(emailc);` will be always false.

If you are using a hashmap as a temporary database for dev purposes then, make it static rather keep it in a different class like UserStore or some DB access layer. Exmaple below:

```
public class UserDAO(){

private static Map<String,User> userdata = new HashMap<String,User>();
public boolean hasUser(String email){
 return userdata.contains(email);
}

public User saveUser(String email, String password ...){
//make user object save it in map and return the same
}

// more methods for delete and edit etc.

}
```

And use this in your REST layer classes like this

```
exists = userDao.hasUser(email);
```

Advantages :

1. Your problem will be solved.
2. Later on when you move to actual db implementation you will just have to change your UserDao code and rest application code will be just fine. -- Loose coupling :)

Also regarding forward using email

```
servletResponse.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/MySite/{email}");  <<<< How to redirect using @FormParam("email")
```

add the email parameter there in the url only, if thats what you want:

```
servletResponse.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/MySite/"+emailc);
```

**UPDATE :**

See the fundamental thing is that you get request parameters `[email , password]`. You check it whether it is present in map or not. Now what you are doing wrong here is you create a new user like this `User u = new User();` and then get email and password from it `emailc = u.getEmail();`. This `emailc` will always be `null` and your `userdata map` will always return `false` for that. You have two choices :

1. Either set email and password in user object and then get the data from user object.
2. Use the email and password obtained from request parameters for your logic. Do not alter them

*One good practice to follow while programming is that at all times think of your method parameters as final parameters.*

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
if(mypass==pass){
                checked=true;
            }else{
                checked=false;
            }
```

Change `==` to `equals` method. `String matching` should be done by `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` method not ==.

Comment: sorry but its still redirecting to Create_Profile page !! have done as you said except that my map contains <String,String> field which are for email and password... and its in UserData class (that shldnt make any diffenece)...also i have changed u1.getEmail to u1.setEmail (same change for pass)...is that right ?

Comment: your userdata maps need to be static and do you ever store login data in that map ? I am thinking that you never store login data in map and hence whenever you will fetch it will always be false/null.

Comment: its a login page...i store the data through Create_Profile page..
like this `userdata.put(email,password);` .. and yes userdata map is static !!

Comment: one more question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184764/how-to-create-build-rest-uri-using-form-parameters

Comment: forget that ...i have now used the constructor for new user:
`User u =new User(emailc,password);`

Comment: nope !!...its not working now also...dont know what i am doing wrong here...hav u luked at this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184764/how-to-create-build-rest-uri-using-form-parameters/17186565

Comment: well are you sure that your map contains some entries ? try adding loggers, sysouts anything. Also i hope you are not initializing userdata somewhere again !

Comment: well i am outputing my map's data in xml form and it contains same entries...but when i try to login using same data it redirects to Create_Profile page

Comment: man what about this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184764/how-to-create-build-rest-uri-using-form-parameters/17186565

Answer (score 0):

You always create a new `User` without any parameters: `User u1=new User();`. All these `User` instances will have the same property values and probably `exists` is always `false`.

Comment: this is just for login purpose and not creating new user...
new users are created at Create_Profile.html !!
i have modified to u1.setemail,ui.setpassword but that too doesnt make any difference !!