# How to create/build REST URI using form parameters

Tags: rest, jersey, uri

okay so i have created restful webservice.now how to create a path for a user "abc".
Something like this

```
http://stackoverflow.com/user/abc
```

Following is my form for getting the user input thorugh html

```
@POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public void newUser(
            @FormParam("uname") String uname,
            @FormParam("password") String password,
            @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse
    ) throws IOException {
        User u = new User(uname,password);
        User.userdata.put(uname,password);
    }
```

How to make a URI something like this from the form parameters if user has uname as "abc"

```
http://mysite/user/abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@Path` and `@PathParam` annotations:

```java
@Path("/user/{uname}")
@PUT
@Consumes("text/plain")
public void putUser(@PathParam("uname") String uname, String password) {
  // ..
}
```

If you `PUT` to `/user/joe` with a body of `s3cret`, then `uname` will be `joe` and `password` will be `s3cret`.

I use `PUT` because the URL you want to use implies that the username is set by the client. `/user` is the collection resource of all users.

**Edit:** Since this method will change the server state by creating a new user, `PUT` or `POST` must be used. `GET` *must not* change the server state.

Comment: so i need to create this method `putUser` to which a user will be redirected by using this at the end of newUser : `servletResponse.sendRedirect("http://mysite/user/"+uname);` ... ??

dont you think it should be `GET` ??

Comment: @Accepts("text/plain") << this is undefined !!
do you wanna say @Consume ??

Comment: but how will i use this in html form if i need to redirect a user to his pics..
`http://mysite/user/{user}/pics` ...well this doesnt use rest's dynamic approach !!

Comment: getting error Apache Tomcat Error 405 !! its going to `http://mysite/user/abc` but giving this error !! ..
Error 405 Methiod Not ALLOWED !!

Comment: Yes, only `PUT` is accepted. You asked about how an URL might look that includes the username. I've answered that. Since your question is tagged 'jersey' and 'rest', my answer describes a way that is RESTful.

Comment: @user2416728 change your method annotation i.e. from "@PUT" to whatever you are using it will work.