# How to construct a URI path according to the formparams in REST jersey

Tags: rest, jersey, uri

First read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184764/how-to-create-build-rest-uri-using-form-parameters) .

Now i had known how to construct it grammatically...but how to ACCEPT a forms parameters,PROCESS it and CONSTRUCT a URI accordingly is still unkown !!

My form :

```
@POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public void newUser(
            @FormParam("uname") String uname,
            @FormParam("password") String password,
            @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse
    ) throws IOException {
        User u = new User(uname,password);
        User.userdata.put(uname,password);
    }
```

i will recieve it like this :

```
@Path("/user/{uname}")
@PUT
@Consumes("text/plain")
public void putUser(@PathParam("uname") String uname, String password) {
  // ..
}
```

But the path
`http://mysite/users/abc`
for a user "abc" doesn't seem to exists..
apache is giving error 405 method not allowed...

I am asking how to construct that path by processing parameters in my form...

Comment: are those web service methods in the same resource? the same web app?

Comment: you need to say i must make an extra class for some methods ?

Comment: No, just trying to understand your env better. If they're in the same class you don't really need to go through http, why don't you just call putUser() method directly from newUser? Or if you do it from within userdata.put() pass this as an argument to call putUser() on the resource directly?